# Is there a free online credit report service in Canada?

Tags: canada, credit-report, free

[This question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/359/how-can-one-get-their-fico-credit-scores-for-free-really-free) refers to the AnnualCreditReport.com service in the United States.

Similarly, is there a **free** online credit report service in **Canada**?

Comment: This is not a product or service recommendation question.  This is about obtaining your own credit report for free, which is an important ability.  It needs to remain open, because the answer may change in the future.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, as far as I know, a **free** credit report is only available by mail. Here's [a page](http://canadian-creditreport.com/freebymail.htm) with contact information for Equifax and TransUnion for ordering a credit report by mail.

Also note that anyone offering free online credit reports in Canada is lying through their teeth. There are a couple sites out there (e.g., canadafreecreditscore.ca, freecreditreportsincanada.ca) that offer a "free" online credit report in seconds, but that's just the hook line and sinker for [signing up for a 7-day trial and then $29.95/mo afterward](http://www.redflagdeals.com/forums/free-credit-report-580142/). Not sure of the details, but I generally avoid anything that's not Equifax or TransUnion for credit reports.

Comment: +1, good answer.  Except, I suggest we avoid linking to products that claim to be free but aren't.  I've edited your post to simply mention the sites and not link to them - I hope you don't mind!

Comment: It's really unfortunate that our government hasn't mandated free credit reports yet.

Answer (score 1):

As far as we know, you can't get a free credit report online, like fideli said.  But you can order a free credit report by **phone** or by **mail**.

For instructions on how to do both, see this blog post:

Dianne Nice.  ["It's easy to get a free credit report. Honest!"](http://www.theglobeandmail.com/globe-investor/personal-finance/home-cents/its-easy-to-get-a-free-credit-report-honest/article1857514/).  Globe Investor Home Cents blog entry.  The Globe and Mail, Inc.  5 January 2011.  Retrieved 16 January 2011.